# Can I be homophobic

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, fiqh, women, men

Asalamu alyakum wa rah matullahi rabarakaatu, so my question is can I be homophobic, like just disliking the lgbt people only & not making fun or bullying them & not supporting them as lgbt. & if I’m homophobic by disliking thoses types of people then is it a sin? Also can a person be lgbt but not telling others they are & it being between them & Allah swt & are not committing the act? I’m asking this cuz I told others that u can be but shouldn’t act upon the sin & you can’t tell others that, so if telling people that will I get sins for it or something?

Comment: Please use relevant tags, focus your post to one indivisible question and elaborate that question fully.

Comment: "homophobia" a slur. referring to an aversion towards homosexuality, is a natural feeling emergent from the fitrah which determines it as revolting. There was a study done that showed straight men have the same psychological reaction to gays kissing as we do to rotting meat. , the fact your question is worded as if treading on eggshells proves how effective LGBT "progress" has been on society. In fact, a general dislike for people who make it their life's mission to infect society with gunk is a sign of your sound mental health.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be expressive of the hatred and it is not a sin if you tell others that homosexuality is not the right way. however you need to be aware of your tone as hatred is not a good thing. And quom e lut is cursed upon so I believe there is nothing wrong with disliking them but I think it is better to stay quiet because only Allah Swt can judge them. secondly it is not haram to find the same gender attractive because it is not in our control but if we act upon it, that is haram.